# Writing to file best practises (locked files/overwriting)

Tags: c#

If I am working with files in C#, what is the best way to check if a file is locked in C#?

If I use File.OpenWrite(), which returns a FileStream, and this returns CanWrite = false, is this a way of checking so?

Also, what is it wise to write to just one location in my code? So I specify a path to write to like "TestExample.txt", but then if I run my code, successfully write to the file, run again, the same data will be in there. Is it possible to overwrite the data already in a file altogether? Or do I need to manually delete (I know this sounds naive).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`File.OpenWrite` will throw an `IOException` if the file is locked, so calling that method and then checking the `CanWrite` property would not be a good approach. You will need a try-catch handling the `IOException`.

If you want to replace the contents of your file, you can simply delete it before writing to it (if it exists):

```
try
{
    if (File.Exists(fileName))
    {
        File.Delete(fileName);
    }
    using (FileStream stream = File.OpenWrite(fileName))
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    {
        writer.Write("your content");
    }        
}
catch (IOException)
{
    // the file is locked
}
```